# Clicking on a cell fires the "on change" event for every single cell in the row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the editor plugin for my datatables.net table.

When I click a cell to edit inline like so:

[image]

It fires the `onChange` event for every single cell as if the value was changed in every cell.

```
  editor.field('to_date').input().on( 'change', function (e,d) {

    console.log("to_date event fired")
  });
```

This is how I have created my table

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
          data: data,
          table: "#adSets",
          fields: [ {
                  name: "interest_id"
              },{
                  name: "interest_fb_id"
              },{
                  name: "adset_name"
              }, {
                  name: "budget"
              }, {
                  name: "duration",
                  type:  "select",
                  options: [
                    { label: 'Daily', value: 'Daily' },
                    { label: 'Lifetime', value: 'Lifetime' }
                  ]   
              }, {
                  type: "datetime",
                  name: "from_date",
                  readonly: true,
                  format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'
              }, {
                  type: "datetime",
                  name: "to_date",
                  readonly: true,
                  format: 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A'
              }
          ]
      } );

  adSetsTable = $('#adSets').DataTable( {
      data: data,
      bPaginate: false,
      bFilter: false,
      bInfo: false,
      columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: [ 0, 1 ],
            visible: false
        }
      ],
      columns: [
          { title: "Interest Id", data: "interest_id", className: 'text-left'},
          { title: "Interest Fb Id", data: "interest_fb_id", className: 'text-left'},
          { title: "Adset Name", data: "adset_name", className: 'text-left'},
          { title: "Budget", data: "budget", className: 'text-right', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) },
          { title: "Duration", data: "duration", className: 'text-right'},
          { title: "Start Date", data: "from_date", className: 'text-right'},
          { title: "End Date", data: "to_date", className: 'text-right' }
      ]
  } );

      editor.field('from_date').disable();
      editor.field('to_date').disable();

      // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
      $('#adSets').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this, {
            onBlur: 'submit'
        });

      });
```

I am not sure if maybe I initiated the table the wrong way?

Here is a video showing the issue in case someone wants to take a look. https://streamable.com/s9fzm

It automatically loses the edit mode because the onChange is firing and i am calling `adSetsTable.rows().invalidate().draw();`

Comment: Seems like this issue is similar to this one https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46864/update-field-value-based-on-another-field-changed-inline the only issue is that i cant just use a keydown event because i also have a drop down and datetime picker inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the change event firing after a click in intended functionality according to [this thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46864/update-field-value-based-on-another-field-changed-inline)

Just solved it.

Changed the event i'm listening to the blur event since my issue was an intended functionality.

Changed:

```
.input().on( 'change', function (e,d) {
```

To:

```
.input().on( 'blur', function (e,d) {
```

The changed value is committed after the user leaves the input so this works out perfectly for my scenario.

If you are just using text inputs you can you the `keydown` event, however i had dropdown and date-picker inputs that would not fire the `keydown` event so i had to use the `blur` event.

Comment: You are right, @ricks, I have to use blur event as on older version of datatable editor 
(https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39837/datetime-field-does-not-fire-change-event )
Change event not works while selecting datetime by clicking on calendar.

editor.field('field_name').input().on('blur', function () { 
        // need setTimeout as it will load value after completing event
        setTimeout(function(){  
            console.log(editor.field('field_name').val())                       
        },1000);
        
});

os I had to use

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem persist even while using the edit functions included with the Datatables library? Looks like cell edits can be done via the cell().edit() function as described in the documentation here:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().edit()

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nope, same scenario is happening if i switch it to cell().edit()